# How do I update a Gtk.Box object in a callback function?

Tags: python, pygobject

I want to add an entry on both columns when I click on the button.
This is my current code.
The python interpreter says MainWindow object has no attribute `a`.

<del>How can I access the objects `a` and `b` from the function on_adding?</del>
Now the new problem is, how can I show the newly created objects?
I tried:
adding it to the `vbox` object in the function `on_adding`.

How can I update the `hbox`

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository
import Gtk, GObject

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self): #initiate
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.set_border_width(17)
        self.set_default_size(700, 400)

        # defining objects
        hb = Gtk.HeaderBar()
        hbox = Gtk.Box(spacing = 7)
        vbox0 = Gtk.Box(orientation = Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        vbox1 = Gtk.Box(orientation = Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        save_button = Gtk.Button("Save")
        hintlabel0 = Gtk.Label("Entry A")
        hintlabel1 = Gtk.Label("Entry B")
        add_button = Gtk.Button("New Entry")
        a = list()
        b = list()

        # appending
        a.append(a_entry())
        b.append(b_entry())

        # property setting
        hb.set_show_close_button(True)
        hb.props.title = "Cerebrium List Editor"
        self.set_titlebar(hb)
        hb.pack_end(save_button)
        hb.pack_end(add_button)
        add_button.connect("clicked", self.on_adding)


        # adding
        vbox0.add(hintlabel0)
        vbox1.add(hintlabel1)
        for i in range(0, len(a)):
            vbox0.add(a[i])
        for i in range(0, len(b)):
            vbox1.add(b[i])

        hbox.add(vbox0)
        hbox.add(vbox1)
        self.add(hbox)# flow control

        def on_adding(self, button):
            self.a.append(a_entry())
            self.b.append(b_entry())


class a_entry(Gtk.Entry):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Entry.__init__(self)
        self.set_width_chars(25)

class b_entry(Gtk.Entry):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Entry.__init__(self)
        self.set_width_chars(60)

win = MainWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

> The python interpreter says MainWindow object has no attribute "a".

To simply solve that you have to set `self.a` not `a` which is a local variable.

I find your lists to be odd though, just directly modify the Gtk.Box contents.

Comment: No more errors this time, but would it be added to the `vbox0` and `vbox1`? It doesn't seem to show an extra entry when I click on it.

Comment: No, it still won't show the new Entries. The reason I want to use a list is I can get the information out much more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
add_button.connect("clicked", self.on_adding)
```

to this

```
add_button.connect("clicked", self.on_adding, vbox0, vbox1)
```

and this

```
def on_adding(self, button):
    self.a.append(a_entry())
    self.b.append(b_entry())
```

to this, and don't forget `show()` mentioned in the comments above

```
def on_adding(self, button, vbox0, vbox1):
    entry = a_entry()
    self.a.append(entry)
    vbox0.add(entry)

    entry = b_entry()
    self.b.append(entry)
    vbox1.add(entry)
```